# Regular expressions to remove space and whitespace in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for regular expressions to remove space and whitespace  before and after a comma.

Comment: Perhaps you could accept an answer?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', $str);
```

This will replace all commas with possible leading and trailing whitespace characters (`\s`) by a single comma.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', $target_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex for this.

```
$output = explode(',', $input);
$output = array_map('trim', $output);
$output = implode(',', $output);
```

Comment: True, but regex (especially a trivial one like this) should be significantly more efficient than mapping functions and multiple data type conversions...

Comment: This is going to trim new lines from before/after commas in addition to the whitespace.  If that's acceptable, it's definitely the fastest option.

Comment: I guess it's really a question of which you find more readable. I find what I've posted to be easier to comprehend than a regex, but that's because I don't deal with regexes a lot. I can see how someone might find the regex approach easier to understand at a glance, and that counts for a lot.

Comment: @ircmaxell ~30% faster on my machine for ~1000 character text blobs littered with commas

Comment: This is also going to remove spaces/newlines from the outer edges of the text. Ex. "   Some text , other text.  " would become "Some text,other text."